# Removing a fields from a dynamic ModelForm

Tags: django, dynamic, field, modelform

In a ModelForm, i have to test user permissions to let them filling the right fields :

It is defined like this:

```
class TitleForm(ModelForm):    
    def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TitleForm,self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)            
        choices = ['','----------------']
        # company
        if user.has_perm("myapp.perm_company"): 
            self.fields['company'] = forms.ModelChoiceField(widget=forms.HiddenInput(),
                queryset=Company.objects.all(), required=False) 
            choices.append(1,'Company')
        # association
        if user.has_perm("myapp.perm_association")
            self.fields['association'] =
            forms.ModelChoiceField(widget=forms.HiddenInput(),
                queryset=Association.objects.all(), required=False)
            choices.append(2,'Association')
        # choices
        self.fields['type_resource'] = forms.ChoiceField(choices = choices)

    class Meta:
        Model = Title
```

This ModelForm does the work : i hide each field on the template and make them appearing thanks to javascript...
The problem is this ModelForm is that each field defined in the model will be displayed on the template.
I would like to remove them from the form if they are not needed:
**exemple : if the user has no right on the model Company, it won't be used it in the rendered form in the template.**

The problem of that is you have to put the list of fields in the Meta class of the form with **fields** or **exclude** attribute, but i don't know how to manage them dynamically.

Any Idea??
Thanks by advance for any answer.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just delete it from the *self.fields* dict:

```
if not user.has_perm("blablabla"):
    del self.fields["company"]
```

Comment: Yes, it was obvious!!!! Just have to define all the fields in the Meta class and then removing if not usefull...
Thanks a lot!

Comment: this won't work if you have fieldset specified on for example in a ModelAdmin.

Comment: @NathanKeller quick and dirty: `self.fields['field_to_hide'] = forms.CharField(required=False, widget=forms.HiddenInput())`

Comment: modifying forms after __init__ has been called has always felt a bit hackish to me. you have to be very cautious what you do! (still in 2018!)